# Rate limit exceeded, code 88 when trying to access a persons "following" list

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I've been trying to create a simple program which digs through the "following" lists of two twitter users, gathering all of the people that they follow into separate lists and then creating a new list with all of the people that both of the users follow.

My program works for small amounts of users but if I try to access the entire following list the program crashes and gives me the following error:

```
raise RateLimitError(error_msg, resp)
tweepy.error.RateLimitError: [{'message': 'Rate limit exceeded', 'code': 88}]
```

Here's the code that I've written so far:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)

followingList = []

for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, screen_name="user1").items():
    followingList.append(user.screen_name)


followingList2 = []

for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, screen_name="user2").items():
    followingList.append(user.screen_name)


for friend in followingList:
    if friend in followingList2:
        print(friend)
    else:
        print("Not following")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour, since the Twitter API only allows 15 requests in a 15 minute window to the friends/followers endpoints. You will need to handle this in your code.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, Andy! Do you have any tips on how I could handle this? I've been looking for answers everywhere, but I keep running into dead-ends every time.